# Not sure how to display sprite

Tags: python-3.x, class, pygame, sprite

I'm trying to spawn an enemy for my game, and I was told that updating my sprite group would do that. For some reason, the enemy doesn't spawn at all. Not getting any errors or anything. Here's my class:

```
class Spawn(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self,primaryx,primaryy):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        global directionM
        self.directionM=directionM
        x1=random.randint(100,400)
        y1=random.randint(100,400)
        self.x1=x1
        self.y1=y1
        self.primaryx=primaryx
        self.primaryy=primaryy
    def AIPrototype(self):
        minionup=pygame.image.load("Alien.png").convert_alpha()
        miniondown=pygame.image.load("Aliendown.png").convert_alpha()
        minionleft=pygame.image.load("Alienleft.png").convert_alpha()
        minionright=pygame.image.load("Alienright.png").convert_alpha()
        global x,y,posx,posy
        seperate=random.randint(1,1000)
        screen.blit(self.directionM,(self.primaryx,self.primaryy))
        if seperate==2:
            self.primaryx=x+100
        if seperate==20:
            self.primaryx=x-100
        if seperate==150:
            self.primaryy=y+100
        if seperate==200:
            self.primaryy=y-100
        self.x1=self.primaryx
        self.y1=self.primaryy
        if self.x1<x:
            xspeed1=1
            slopex1=x-self.x1
        if self.x1>x:
            xspeed1=-1
            slopex1=self.x1-x
        if self.y1<y:
            yspeed1=1
            slopey1=y-self.y1
        if self.y1>y:
            yspeed1=-1
            slopey1=self.y1-y       
    #
        hypo1=((slopex1**2)+(slopey1**2))**0.5
        speedmark1=hypo1/1
        speedy1=slopey1/speedmark1
        speedx1=slopex1/speedmark1
        movex1=speedx1
        movey1=speedy1
        if self.x1<=640 and self.x1>=0:
            if self.x1>x:
                self.x1+=xspeed1*movex1
                if self.x1<x:
                    xspeed1=0
        if self.y1<=480 and self.x1>=0:
            if self.y1>y:
                self.y1+=yspeed1*movey1
                if self.y1<y:
                    yspeed1=0
        if self.x1<=640 and self.x1>=0:
            if self.x1<x:
                self.x1+=xspeed1*movex1
                if self.x1>x:
                    xspeed1=0
        if self.y1<=480 and self.x1>=0:
            if self.y1<y:
                self.y1+=yspeed1*movey1
                if self.y1>y:
                    yspeed1=0
    #
        if self.x1>640:
            self.x1=640
        if self.x1<0:
            self.x1=0
        if self.y1>480:
            self.y1=480
        if self.y1<0:
            self.y1=0
        if self.y1>=posy-20 and self.y1<=posy+20 and self.x1>=x-20 and self.x1<=x+20:
            Spawn.kill()
        self.primaryx=self.x1
        self.primaryy=self.y1
```

And here's where I call it and everything:

```
spritegroup = pygame.sprite.Group()
spawn = Spawn(600,200)
spritegroup.add(spawn)
clock = pygame.time.Clock() 
keepGoing = True        

try:
    while keepGoing:
        clock.tick(60) 
        screen.fill(THECOLORS['red'])
        char()#start
        x+1
        posxlist.append(x)
        posylist.append(y)
        spritegroup.update()
        spritegroup.draw(screen)
        pygame.display.flip()
```

How do I display/call the sprite? I apologize for my messy and ineffecient code. I'm new to using classes and sprites.

Answer (score 0):

Calling `spritegroup.update()` doesn't spawn new sprites, it calls the `update` method of all contained sprites. Since your `Spawn` sprite subclass doesn't have an `update` method, `spritegroup.update()` actually has no effect in your progam.

You can spawn new sprites by creating an instance and adding it to the sprite group like you did here:

```
spawn = Spawn(600, 200)
spritegroup.add(spawn)
```

Comment: More information about sprites and sprite groups can be found in [Program Arcade Games](http://programarcadegames.com/index.php?chapter=introduction_to_sprites&lang=de#section_13) (the previous chapter is about classes).

Comment: But I did that in the code, and no sprites were spawned. Right?

Comment: Your sprite class also needs a `self.image` (a pygame.Surface) and a `self.rect` (a pygame.Rect) attribute to work correctly. I overlooked that because your example wasn't complete and I couldn't test it. You should edit the code in your question and provide a [minimal, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). And read the tutorial that I linked above, since it will teach you the basics.